# Python: replace part of file path using pandas match

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, filepath

Data frame with 2 columns: `old_path` and `new_path`. Data frame can contain hundreds of rows.

The script iterates over a list of files.

For each file in the list, check if any part of its folder path matches a value in the `old_path` column. If there is a match, replace the file's matched `old_path` with the corresponding `new_path` value.

I achieved this with `for index, row in df.iterrows():` or `for row in df.itertuples():`, but I'm thinking there should be a more efficient way to do it without having to use the second `for` loop.

Any help is appreciated. Sample below uses `df.iterrows()`

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('path_lookup.csv')
# df:
#                                         old_path                      new_path
# 0               F:\Business\Budget & Forecasting  M:\Business\Finance\Forecast
# 1                    F:\Business\Treasury Shared  M:\Business\Finance\Treasury
# 2                                        C:\Temp                    C:\NewTemp

excel_link_analysis_list = [
    {'excel_filename': 'C:\\Temp\\12345\\Distribution Adjusted Claim.xlsx',
     'file_read': 'OK'},
    {'excel_filename': 'C:\\Temp\\SubFolder\\cost estimates.xlsx',
     'file_read': 'OK'}
]

for i in excel_link_analysis_list:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['old_path'].lower() in i['excel_filename'].lower():
            dest_path_and_file = i['excel_filename'].lower().replace(row['old_path'].lower(), 
                                                                     row['new_path'].lower())
            print(dest_path_and_file)
```

prints:

> c:\newtemp\12345\distribution adjusted claim.xlsx
>
> c:\newtemp\subfolder\cost estimates.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pandas has nice built in string comparison functions, see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains

This is how you could use `Series.str.contains` to get the index of the matching value (i.e. from the column `old_path`). You could then use that index to go back and get the value of `new_path`

Edit: updated to handle the case where new_path_matches has one value.

```
import pandas as pd

old_path = df['old_path']
new_path = df['new_path']

for filename in filenames:
    b = old_path.str.contains(filename)

    # Get the index of matches from `old_path` column
    indeces_of_matches = b[b].index.values    

    # use the index of matches to get the corresponding `new_path' values 
    new_path_matches = old_path.loc[indeces_of_matches]

    if (new_path_matches.value.shape[0]>0):
        print new_path_matches.values[0]   # print the new_path value
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. When running the above, slighty modified, I get an error: `raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
sre_constants.error: bad escape \T at position 2` on line: `b = old_path.str.contains(i['excel_filename'])`. Thinking it has to do with the backslashes in the filepaths.

Comment: Fixed it by changing to `b = old_path.str.contains(i['excel_filename'], regex=False, case=False)`. This still does not match though. All iterations return `False` if you do a `print(b)` immediately afterwards.

Comment: It now successfully matches after adding the following: `file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(i['excel_filename']))` and then changed the next line to read `b = old_path.str.contains(file_path, case=False, regex=False).any()`. Now getting a new error `indices_of_matches = b[b].index.values` gives error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: That's because the call to `.any()` returns a numpy array rather than a series. What happens if you print b?

Comment: Removing the call to `.any()` works. Printing b gives `0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: old_path, dtype: bool`, which is great. Last line: `print(new_path_matches[0])` gives `KeyError: 0` though.

Comment: Sounds like we're almost there. Try print(new_path_matches.values[0])

Comment: Sorry, I tested with different `excel_link_analysis_list` data earlier. Printing b actually returns all False: `0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: old_path, dtype: bool`. For some reason this line doesn't seem to match anything: `b = old_path.str.contains(i['excel_filename'], case=False, regex=False)`

Comment: Hmm. Doing this works for me: new_path = pd.Series(['C:\\Temp\\12345\\Distribution Adjusted Claim.xlsx'])
searchstr = 'C:\\Temp\\12345\\Distribution Adjusted Claim.xls'

print searchstr
b = new_path.str.contains(searchstr,regex=False,case=False)
indeces_of_matches = b[b].index.values
Only thing I can suggest from here is to double check the way you are storing backslashes/filenames.